# Erro no render do Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Toda vez que eu abro um arquivo de layout não aparece a preview e aparece um erro no log de eventos. Não é um layout específico, são todos layouts.

Tem um [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677760/android-studio-1-1-0-render-error) igual na versão em inglês, mas já possui um ano e está sem resposta.

Erro:

```
com/xxxx/xxxx/activity/R$mipmap
java.lang.ClassFormatError: com/xxxx/xxxx/activity/R$mipmap
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses(Class.java:1867)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.parseClass(ViewLoader.java:562)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadAndParseRClass(ViewLoader.java:546)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadAndParseRClassSilently(ViewLoader.java:502)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadAndParseRClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:663)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.<init>(RenderTask.java:153)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createTask(RenderService.java:198)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:649)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Update:**

Troquei a versão do android no preview de design como dito [neste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems) post, não resolveu.

**Update 2:**

Procurei atualizações pro Android Studio, reinstalei o mesmo e instalei todos os pacotes pelo SDK Manager novamente, também não resolveu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após horas tentando, criei um novo projeto no Android Studio pra copiar os arquivos do projeto para um novo projeto (minha última esperança). Criado o projeto o render voltou a funcionar normalmente. Provavelmente é algum bug do Android Studio, onde já reportei o mesmo.